# Check swiss phone number using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if the Swiss number is entered, I used this Regex, and it shows me that it is correct.
https://www.regextester.com/115572

```
var filter = /^([0][1-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9])$|^(([0][0]|\+)[1-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9])$/;
```

What am I doing wrong to always get false, and fall into else where validphone = 0;

```js
var phone = $("#phone").val();
  
  var filter = /^([0][1-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9])$|^(([0][0]|\+)[1-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9](\s|)[0-9][0-9])$/;
        
        
        if (filter.test(phone)) {
            $( ".validphone .help-block.with-errors" ).html( '' );
            var validphone = 1;
        }
        else {
            $( ".validphone .help-block.with-errors" ).html( '<ul class="list-unstyled"><li>Telefonnummer ist nicht korrekt!</li></ul>' );
            var validphone = 0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="form-group validphone">
<input class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Telefonnummer*" required data-error="Telefonnummer fehlt!">
    <div class="input-group-icon">
  <i class="fas fa-phone"></i></div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your input that fails?

Comment: Hi @AsteroidsWithWings input ="0796661624"

Comment: Tip: `[0-9]{2}` instead of `[0-9][0-9]`, `\s?` instead of `(\s|)`.

Comment: @tadman Please correct your code on the entire regex.

Comment: That's an exercise for you. I'm just offering advice that will *significantly* simplify what you're doing. If you're not interested, you can continue to make life difficult for yourself for no reason.

Comment: @tadman I corrected but the same result

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/apko14yj/).